# How can I get my HyperVisor running?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

Nearly all Google results tell me to enable it in the BIOS settings of my Lenovo T520i, but the only relevant setting I see there is `Virtualisation`, which is set to `enabled`. The Hyper-V manager works alright, and creates a new VM for me, but then when I try and start the VM, I get the "HyperVisor not running" message.

I think this happened somewhere trying to set up a virtual device for debugging Android, and I was asked if the Hypervisor could be turned off, as it interferes with the emulators own virtualisation. I just said, "Yes, get on with it."

Comment: Have you tried opening a cmd prompt with admin credentials and enter the following:  dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

Comment: run **bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto** reboot and look if it works now.

Comment: Hyper-V is an OS feature, Hardeare Virtualization is a x86 extension and a feature of your hardware, two separate things entirely.  Hardware Virtualization also isn't required for a Hypervisor.

Comment: @Ramhound VT-x is required ;) "The following items will need to be enabled in the system BIOS: Virtualization Technology - may have a different label depending on motherboard manufacturer." https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Its required for Hyper-V but for others.

Comment: @Ramhound next time read the question again. he askes for Hyper-V * facepalm*

Comment: I did read the question.  But was making a general statement it's not always required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a cmd prompt with admin credentials and enter the following:

> dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All